# Mild climate, low-humidity city all year round

Tags: meteorology, climate, humidity

Where in the world can I find a place with mild / warm and non-humid climate all year round?

What I'm looking for is a city with these characteristics:
- monthly average low temperature > 5°C (41°F)
- monthly average high temperature < 27°C (81°F)
- low humidity levels
- at least 500k people
- English or Spanish as first language

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "non-humid" means, in terms of relative humidity? Just based on your temperature range limits, such place very likely doesn't exist. Even Miami FL (tropical climate) dips below 5C once every few years. Most places on Earth hit extremes on occasions. Using quartiles or 10/90 percentiles may be more useful.

Comment: I'm not sure this question has much to do with Earth Science - it sounds more like 'where can I move to?' (languages??). Can you explain why you need this info?

Comment: if you wish such small range of temperature you need a city close to the sea, but when you're close to the sea the humidity is always high, unless your're close to a desert. Maybe a city like Valparaiso in Chile might be close to your needs, even though smaller places like Arica (in the same country) is better.

Comment: @milancurcic I edited my question so that it doesn't say "never".

Comment: My answer to https://www.quora.com/Which-cities-and-towns-have-a-climate-of-year-round-comfort-eternal-spring doesn't really answer your question, but may help. Ultimately, you could grab the data yourself and search, though this seems like overkill. Googling might work just as well.

Comment: Little Italy, San Diego, California.

Comment: @BarryCarter -- I didn't look at the quora.com question until now. That question is much more specific than this one, and the answer is the same answer as my one liner: San Diego, CA. Costa Rica's Central Valley is also a close fit, but the humidity is higher.

Comment: @DavidHammen Quora banned me and removed my answer, which would have also answered this question. I'll try to reconstruct it here at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Low humidity means nowhere near the coast or near any large lakes. Warm winter temperatures without being too hot in summer means tropical high elevation or lower latitude inland sub-tropical. Parts of sub-Saharan Africa might suit, although cities like Kampala or Nairobi have relative humidities which reach the high 70s. As Milancuric writes, you need to be more specific about 'low humidity'.